# Edit XML ID value with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

how do i set a value for an XML file?
this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<settings version="2">
<setting id="noteid">266</setting>
</settings>
```

this is my code but it's not working

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\EA\Desktop\settings.xml '
$xml=New-Object XML
$xml.Load($filePath)
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes('/settings/noteid');
foreach($node in $nodes)
{
$node.SetAttribute('type', '1234');
}
$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Did some searching but nothing works for me.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have given us a really shortened example of what the XML looks like, so I extended it a bit here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings version="2">
    <setting id="noteid">266</setting>
    <setting id="someotherid">12345</setting>
    <setting id="anothersettingsid">987</setting>
</settings>
```

You can use either the 'dot' (Case-Insensitive) method for changing the value of the setting with id 'noteid' like this:

```powershell
$newNoteId = 987654321
$filePath  = 'C:\Users\EA\Desktop\settings.xml'
[xml]$xml  = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw

($xml.settings.setting | Where-Object { $_.id -eq 'noteid' }).InnerText = $newNoteId

$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Or use XPath (remember that this is Case-Sensitive..)

```powershell
$newNoteId = 987654321
$filePath  = 'C:\Users\EA\Desktop\settings.xml'
[xml]$xml  = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw

$xml.SelectNodes('//setting[@id="noteid"]') | ForEach-Object { $_.InnerText = $newNoteId }

$xml.Save($filePath)
```

In both cases the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings version="2">
  <setting id="noteid">987654321</setting>
  <setting id="someotherid">12345</setting>
  <setting id="anothersettingsid">987</setting>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumed your XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings version="2">
    <setting id="noteid">266</setting>
</settings>
```

And you know where you want to change the value you can use the dot notation to access the particular node you're after:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\EA\Desktop\settings.xml'
[XML]$xml = Get-Content -Path $filePath

$xml.settings.setting.'#text' = '12345'

$xml.Save($filePath)
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to this.
How to i set it to change the value of this sepcific ID'

Comment: What do you mean "how"? Exactly how I showed it. Did you try the code I suggested?

Comment: yes and it showsThe property '#text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and ca
n be set.

Comment: What's your Powershell version? Does your XML file really looks like you showed in your question?